# How is stdarg Provided in the C++ Runtime

Tags: c++, linux, embedded, header-files, variadic-macros

**Background:**

While setting up YouCompleteMe compile arguments for a standalone GCC + sysroot for aarch64, I went spelunking in the standard C++ system includes and found this little gem:

**[sysroot]/usr/include/c++/11.2.0/cstdarg**

```
#include <stdarg.h>
```

Which points at

**[sysroot]/usr/include/c++/11.2.0/tr1/stdarg.h**

```
#include <tr1/cstdarg>
```

Which, itself, points at

**[sysroot]/usr/include/c++/11.2.0/tr1/cstdarg**

```
#include <cstdarg>
```

Thereby looping us back to the beginning.  The loop is ultimately broken by some `#ifdef`'s but, ultimately, none of these files really defines anything substantial.

Since these three files all really just include other files, this is causing clangd (YCM's back-end compile server) to  eventually parse

```
namespace std
{
  using ::va_list;
} // namespace std
```

from `[sysroot]/usr/include/c++/11.2.0/cstdarg` and then emit:

```
No member named 'va_list' in the global namespace
```

I double checked my standard system headers and they are essentially identical so this isn't just limited to my cross toolchain.

**Questions:**

1. Where is `va_list` ultimately defined for C++?
2. What arguments would I need to feed to clangd to resolve this?
3. What is the purpose of defining system headers like this?

**Reference:**

The relevant compile arguments are:

```
'-xc++',
'-std=gnu++17',
'-stdlib=libc++',
'-nostdinc',
'-isystem', SYSROOT_AARCH64 + '/usr/include',
'-isystem', SYSROOT_AARCH64 + '/usr/include/linux',
'-isystem', SYSROOT_AARCH64 + '/usr/include/c++/11.2.0',
'-isystem', SYSROOT_AARCH64 + '/usr/include/c++/11.2.0/tr1',
'-isystem', SYSROOT_AARCH64 + '/usr/include/c++/11.2.0/aarch64-poky-linux',
```

**Comment Responses:**

@PasserBy: Where are you seeing that?  The only `stdarg.h` I have is under `c++/11.2.0/tr1` (see comment response to teapot418 below) and this does not have any typedefs in it.  The total content of this file (minus comments) is:

```
#ifndef _TR1_STDARG_H
#define _TR1_STDARG_H 1

#include <tr1/cstdarg>

#endif
```

This matches my host system's `stdarg.h` so I don't think this is a failing of the toolchain.

@Lundin: I am not using this but it looks like `<string>` eventually includes `<cstdarg>` which causes clangd errors.

@teapot418: I had considered this when I noticed that other headers were included as `<tr1/foo>`.  The problem, though, is that removing `tr1` as an include directory causes `stdarg.h` to not be found at all.  A simple find reveals:

```
$ find /path/to/sysroot/ -name stdarg.h
/path/to/sysroot/usr/include/c++/11.2.0/tr1/stdarg.h
```

This is strange to me as I would have expected to find the C version of `stdarg.h` somewhere like `[sysroot]/usr/include`.  I would be wrong, though, as comparing to my host system yields the same result:

```
$ find /usr/include/ -name stdarg.h
/usr/include/c++/12/tr1/stdarg.h
```

Is there some other shenanigans going on here that I am missing?

@KamilCuk: See below.  One thing I notice is that the pats are being included from `.../sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/...` while I was primarily using paths from `.../sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/...`.  Yocto generates both of these as part of the SDK and, I admit, I don't fully appreciate the difference between the two.  I would have expected all relevant headers to be in the `aarch64-poky-linux` but, clearly, this assumption is false.

```
aarch64-poky-linux-gcc -E -xc - <<<'#include <stdarg.h>'
# 0 "<stdin>"
# 0 "<built-in>"
# 0 "<command-line>"
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "/opt/lmc/sdk/remus/0.31.7/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/11.2.0/include/stdarg.h" 1 3 4
# 40 "/opt/lmc/sdk/remus/0.31.7/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/11.2.0/include/stdarg.h" 3 4

# 40 "/opt/lmc/sdk/remus/0.31.7/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/11.2.0/include/stdarg.h" 3 4
typedef __builtin_va_list __gnuc_va_list;
# 99 "/opt/lmc/sdk/remus/0.31.7/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/11.2.0/include/stdarg.h" 3 4
typedef __gnuc_va_list va_list;
# 2 "<stdin>" 2
```

Comment: I believe `va_list` is a typedef for `__gnuc_va_list` which is a typedef for `__builtin_va_list` which is a compiler builtin. This can be found in stdarg.h.

Comment: Why would you ever use stdarg.h in C++ to begin with? Even in C the rule is to avoid this one like the plague.

Comment: Search the bowels of the C compiler, for a normal non-cross env the file is in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include/stdarg.h` (so not /usr/include)

Comment: And I don't think you should have the `tr1` dir as an include path, that's probably what eclipsed the real file and confused the compiler. `tr1/stdarg.h != stdarg.h`

Comment: Please post the output of `gcc -E -xc - <<<'#include <stdarg.h>'`

Comment: @Lundin one common case would be that you're trying to compile some code that uses it, and you don't want to have to rewrite that code.